# What does this red 'do not' symbol mean?

Tags: 18.04, icons

I'm relatively new to the linux world and to this website. I recently installed Ubuntu Mate and in the upper right hand corner is a red 'do not' or 'no' symbol that when clicked on reveals a blank dropdown menu. Right clicking shows an 'about' option but does not explain what it's for or why it's there.

There were a couple other similar questions with a similar symbol that might have something to do with broken package or unmet dependencies, but the solutions provided did not resolve my problem so I suspect it's a different issue.

[image]

Comment: What does the "About" say?

Comment: The about opens a new window: 'Indicator Applet Complete 1.20.0' with buttons 'credits', 'license', and 'close'

Comment: It's not a "do not" symbol"... That's the Ubuntu (or GNOME?) "missing icon" symbol. It is the default icon which an application gets when it does properly supply an icon to the graphical environment.

Comment: Thanks Alex! That answered my question. I just noticed the same symbol for other applications too.

Comment: You can try to switch theme in `mate-appearance-properties` to something different (for example, *Radiance*). Different themes may have different icon sets. And screenshot of drop-down menu will be useful too (make it interactively with `mate-screenshot --interactive`) to determine the application name.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for the screenshot tip. I believe the missing icon was from Dropbox because it went away after I uninstalled it.  I 'm not sure which fixed the issue, but I tried reinstalling and using the Software Updater tool under Menu--> Administration.